# sdk-3.1.1.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided

Tags: sdk, webrtc, agora.io, videocall

Agora SDK gives me this error and doesn't connect the stream only on the laptop mobile (the mobile screens we create under the responsivity section of Developer tools [Inspect Element]).

It works fine on normal mobiles and laptops but I also get an error for this. Any thing that I'm missing out or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

File a bug with agora. This is most likely using URL.createObjectURL(mediaStream) instead of setting videoElement.srcObject somewhere. And that method (or particular usage of the method) in Chrome 71 according to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=800767

Comment: Sure thing. Thanks for your response. I've reached out to them.